# HBase: execute small job using cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata

I have a Java function that runs on a single HBase row (a `Result`), it takes a `Result` as an input and outputs a `byte[]`. I would like to run this function on 10K-100K HBase rows and collect the results. I have a `List<byte[]>` which is the rows I'd like to run this function on, they are distributed evenly across all regions of the table. I would like to do so under these constraints:

- Not ship all the rows from the server to the client
- No long job init, the entire operations is expected to run in under a second
- Utilize processing power of the Hadoop cluster and not the processing power of the client
- Obviously, not depend upon the size of the HBase table which can be billions of rows

What's the best way to achieve this? I've thought of these options:

- Spark - I'm not sure if this is a good option if my job runs on a tiny % of the number of rows in the table
- Coprocessor - is there a way to run coprocessors in bulk on a `List<byte[]>` of rowkeys and collect the result? Will the work be processed in parallel by the cluster?
- Implementing a custom HBase filter and then doing a bulk `Get` on the `List<byte[]>` with the custom filter - The `Get` will be processed by all region servers in parallel and can run custom logic, but this seems like a hack and I'm not sure a custom filter can return data that wasn't present in one of the columns of the row.

Comment: what is the version of your hbase installation?

Comment: HBase 0.98 but I can upgrade to 1.1 if there's anything I need from it. Thanks.